# ORACLE, SQL-SERVER, HSQL supports rewriteBatchedStatements in JDBC connection?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, jdbc, hsqldb

JDBC `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` with JDBC connection URL on MySQL creates one statement for insert.

Please suggest similar option to this for Oracle, SQL Server and HSQL. Is it supported in these database servers?

My basic requirement is to have single insert/update query for multiple rows. MySQL supports this checked the sql log.

```
insert into temp (id,text) values (1,"abc"), (2,"xyz"),
update temp set text='pqr' where id =1;update temp set text='syz' where id =2;
```

Above queries are getting generated if enable batch insert and `rewritableBatchedStatements=true` in jdbc connection URL.

I need this in HSQL, Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: Have updated a question and detailed requirement.

Comment: Connection property `rewriteBatchedStatements` is a MySQL specific connection property that serves as a workaround for not really having a batch execution feature. It is not a JDBC feature. Database servers like Oracle and - afaik - SQL Server properly support batch execution, so don't need such ugly workarounds.

Comment: _"My basic requirement is to have single insert/update query for multiple rows."_ Why? If a database server supports proper batched statement execution, there should be no need for such a crutch. So why exactly do you have the specific requirement that it should produce that single statement?